# Why do I have this problem with objects in defrule?

Tags: clips

Hello I have a problem when using clips. Whenever I use 2 objects in a defrule the program matches the objects in all possible ways (in the part of the code that I am posting bellow I get 100 printout results, I have 10 instances in Exit_M1 and another 10 in Entrance_M1, also M_1 and Count are 2 different classes), and what I would like to get is the instances of the first and second class respectively. Thank you to however answers you would be of great help.

```
(defrule A_1-Diagnosis2
  (goal bind-values)
  ?y<-(object (is-a M_1))
  ?t<-(object (is-a Count))
  =>
  (bind ?t1 (send ?t get-Exit_M1))
  (bind ?x (send ?y get-Entrance_M1))
  (printout t ?t1 crlf) 
  )
```

Comment: You should include the data in your question and add the output you're expecting. You're not constraining the combinations of the M_1 and Count classes in any way, so the number of times the rule will execute is the product of the instances in the two classes.

Comment: Thank you is there any specific way to constrain the combinations of M_1 and Count?

Comment: Yes. Look through the documentation or any of the examples that come with CLIPS.  Your question is not specific enough to tell you how to constrain the rule to get the behavior you want.